# Ubuntu 15.0 bug (system freezes)

Tags: bug-reporting

I've been using Ubuntu 15.0 without problems for a couple of months, but now it has started freezing.

The screen freezes, the mouse cursor freezes, and the audio stops. My only option, as far as I know, is to shut the computer down by holding the power button.

It never freezes while left alone, nor while watching videos on VLC. It does freeze, seemingly randomly, while watching videos or listening to podcasts *through my browser*. Typically while using SoundCloud or YouTube. Also while navigating web pages.

I've done upgrade/update and tried using a different browser, but the problem keeps occurring. Perhaps it only seems as though the browser is the cause, because I'm using it nearly constantly.

The freeze occurs every 15 minutes or so when in active use.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: My Ubuntu system doesn't freeze as often as it used to (I think removing the second screen has helped), but if it does, I do Left ALT key + SysRq key + B to have it reboot instantly.

Comment: do you have flash installed? if so, disable it in the browsers and try again.